# how to fix ylim in pygal, python

Tags: python, pygal

I tried to create radar graph with pygal. But not able to set ylim. By default its start from zero to maximum value. My data is:

```
import pygal

case1 = [0.549194,34.251384,36.154543,41.913,-139.627415,-20.655737]
case2= [0.549194,31.947443,34.558203,40.005646,-157.190631,-70.267567]
case3=[0.549194,31.436088,41.019637,48.748227,-34.859838,243.311831]


radar_chart = pygal.Radar()
radar_chart.title = 'PBIAS'
radar_chart.x_labels = ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
radar_chart.add('Model1', case1)
radar_chart.add('Model2', case2)
radar_chart.add('Model3', case3)
```

It might be very simple but not able to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't just adjust the scale.
The Radar class will set all values less than zero to zero before it generates the graph.

You could pre-process your data and adjust all values up based on the smallest value below zero, but how to do this might depend on the type of data you are graphing.